# How to get the npm script arguments in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

How can i access these flags -

```
npm run start --appenv=development --build=mobile
```

here i want to achieve the value of appenv and build in my react code

Comment: [Are you using create-react-app?](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Comment: Could you add more information like the relevant `package.json` snippet?

Comment: there's everything basic by default we have package.json with no change

Comment: try using "process.argv". 
something like this.


```const myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log('myArgs: ', myArgs);```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
npm run start -- --appenv=development --build=mobile
```